# Como saber qual é o $location atual

Tags: angularjs, programação-funcional, angularjs-services

Como faço para validar quando há uma alteração na tela e o usuário clica em outro hyperlink para sair da tela, o mesmo não pode permitir.

Existe alguma função pronta do angular que realiza essa verificação?

No momento estou tentando usar a opção de **$location** mas não sei como pego a tela atual do meu sistema.

Se possível peço a ajuda de vocês, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tela?... você quer dizer página (url)? Ou controller? Ou talvez rota?

Comment: Ibotinelly, eu preciso da url, eu verifiquei aqui na internet, mas ainda não testei se vou conseguir ou em fim, vou ter de testar, mas achei a seguinte opção para testar e tentar indicar em qual controller ele deve buscar a função dependendo da url:

- $location.url() - essa função me retorna em qual local do sistema eu estou, dessa forma, acho que vai ficar mais fácil de tratar a verificação, vou testar aqui e informo você se funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar um sistema de rota, como o [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), você consegue fazer essa verificação de diversos modos. Mas antes de prosseguir, devo informar que o você estará fazendo, caso opte por essa alternativa, é verificar o estado (`.state`) que o usuário está tentando acessar e não a `URL` propriamente dita - apesar de também ser possível.

Modos que você pode verificar:

- Ao acessar a página;
- Ao mudar de state;

Ao declarar um `.state`, você deve definir um nome, exemplo:

```
.state('inicio', {
    //configurações aqui
})
```

Deste modo você consegue verificar em qual state ele está, para qual state ele está indo, se existe parâmetros, etc.. Para fazer essa interceptação, você deve usar a seguinte função:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParam, fromState, fromParam) {
    //Intercepta a mudança antes que ela ocorra
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParam, fromState, fromParam) {
    //Intercepta uma mudança com successo
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParam, fromState, fromParam) {
    //Intercepta uma mudança com erro
});
```

De preferência, este código é melhor utilizado dentro do `.run()` assim evita que qualquer outro processo seja iniciado antes das verificações.

---

#### Exemplo prático

Digamos que você possua 2 `.state()`:

- Um com acesso liberado -> `.state('inicio')`
- Um com acesso restrito -> `.state('usuario')`

Dentro do run, você faz as verificações:

- Está indo para o state('usuario')?
- Se sim, ele possui permissão?
- Se não possuir, redirecione para o inicio;

Como ficaria o código:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParam, fromState, fromParam) {
    /*
        Precisa ser no $stateChangeStart para evitar que o state seja carregado
        antes de verificar se ele possui permissão
    */
    if(toState == 'usuario') { //Identifica se ele está acessando o `usuario`
        /*
            Sua função de autenticação vai aqui
            Exemplo:
            val = 1; -> usuario autenticado;
            val = 2; -> usuario não autenticado;
        */
        if(val == 2) {
            //Usuario não está autenticado
            event.preventDefault(); //Evita que o state continue o serviço
            return $state.go('inicio'); //Redireciona para o inicio
        }
    }
});
```

Deste modo você consegue fazer as validações e impedir que ele acesse a página.

---

#### Editado conforme solicitação nos comentários.

O seu objetivo na verdade, é fazer a autenticação do usuário para permitir ou não o acesso a página. Ainda usando o `ui-router` você pode fazer uma declaração de `data` dentro do `.state()` e, sempre que houver alteração de estado, verificar se a data exige login e então fazer a autenticação. Mas não faça isso dentro do controller. Se o usuário chegou ao controller, quer dizer que ele provavelmente já carregou os demais arquivos, nem sempre é uma boa prática.

Exemplo do state com data:

```
.state('inicio', {
    url: 'Inicio',
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    }
})
.state('usuario', {
    url: 'MeusDados',
    data: {
        requireLogin: true
    }
})
```

E agora dentro do run() :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParam, fromState, fromParam) {

    if(toState.data.requireLogin) {
        function validarAutenticacao() {
            //...
        };
        /*
           Sua validação de autenticação
           Ela pode ser a mesma para todos os .state()
           que possuirem requireLogin: true;
           Não precisa mais usar dentro do controller
        */
        if (validaAutenticacao == false) { //Se a autenticação for falsa
            event.preventDefault(); //Impede que a página inicie o carregamento
            //Redirecione o usuario ou faça outra manipulação aqui - como exibir um alerta ou redirecionar para a página anterior.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Celsom, obrigado por ajudar, mas seu código apenas faz a verificação para qual página deve ser direcionado se tiver permissão ou não e no meu caso eu preciso bloquear o redirecionar, ou seja, não pode haver nenhuma ação de redirecionar, ele deve ficar na mesma página se o sistema possui algum dado alterado e a única forma que encontrei de validar essa opção é com o $location,url() e verificar em qual url que ele está e usar o controller da quela pagina verificando se há alguma alteração no cadastro ou não, creio que não tenha sido muito claro, mas consegui entender oque deu como sugestão

Comment: Isso que você deseja fazer é outro tipo de serviço. Você está fazendo uma autenticação e não um controle de rotas. Outro ponto importante, se você está fazendo a autenticação dentro de um controller, sua aplicação não vai ser segura, pois o usuário já chegou no destino final. Além disso, você precisará fazer a autenticação em todos os controllers. Vou editar minha resposta, para essa dúvida.

Comment: @TalesBorn editado.

Comment: na verdade ele não chegou ao controller, porque oque acontece é o seguinte: 1-estou na tela cadUsuario, preenchi alguns campos, cliquei no hyperlink PEDIDOS na sidenav do lado esquerdo, mas ele antes de realizar o $location.pach vai fazer uma verificação na tela atual no controller que já estava em uso para ver se os campos estão em branco ou se já houve alguma alteração nos campos, se já houve essa alteração, aparecerá uma modal na tela informando a mensagem: - você efetuou alterações na tela cad usuario, se vc sair dessa tela agora perderá as alterações, desaja continuar?

Comment: se clicar em sim realiza o $location.patch(), se clicar em não ele permanece na pagina, entendeu?

Comment: Então isso não tem nada relacionado com permissão.. e sim com o fato do usuário ter alterado alguma informação sem ter salvo as alterações ainda?